# trigger jquery click on element with hashtag in url

Tags: jquery

I wanted to know if its possible to trigger a popup by just sending the user to a specific url that contains an "#somerandomword"  at the end of it.

So normally they click a button on the page to trigger the popup, instead i just want the popup to trigger when the user is given a specific link.

Answer (score 3):

This could be easily done on page-load, by simply looking for a hash in the URL:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // the #-prefixed portion of the URL that serves
    // as a fragment identifier for the document, from
    // www.example.com/page#fragment
    // document.location.hash would return #fragment
    let hash = document.location.hash;

    // because the hash identifies a fragment of
    // the document by its id, and the '#' character
    // specifies an id-selector in CSS we pass that
    // value to jQuery to select the correct element
    // and call the click() method - without arguments -
    // to trigger a click event:
    $(hash).click();
});
```

Alternatively, the CSS selector of `:target` selects the element targeted by the hash, so it's also possible to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':target').click();
});
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:target` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo).
- JavaScript:

  - [`document.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location).
  - [`let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).
  - [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).
- jQuery:

  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Comment: From my understanding this is what is happening.

1. We wait till document loads
2. next we store the # that was at end of url in a variable named hash

this is where I get slightly confused.

Say my link was www.google.com/puppies#dog

we use document.location.hash, and store its value of "#dog"  in the variable  "hash"

so hash now contains the value of "#dog"

It seems like there should be some sort of IF statement that says if the value of hash is equal to "#dog" then select the popup button and trigger a click event.

Comment: Possibly, but since you never mentioned in your question that you only want to trigger an event on specific fragments/`id`s that was left out of the answer. Otherwise: yes, that's about what happens.